# How to fix request error for a POST in postman app when there is no input?

Tags: rest, wcf, postman

I have a WCF service implemented in my application which accesses database to give back the response. It is RESTful service.

The below API is a POST Api which takes no input but gives back a json response. Hence I send the data this way in postman, but i am getting this error always. Not able to understand what is the issue.

[image: Postman screenshot]

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/FetchPOLList", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
POLList FetchPOLList();
```

I have another webinvoke in same servicecontract which is working fine. It has json input and json output running on same port.

Can anyone tell me what is the problem with this ??

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem the code snippets seem to me. I noticed that you use ORM framework to get the data from a database. Do you have set up the database connection string correctly? or a problem with database connection. In order to exclude this factor, I suggest you return the fixed data first. 
Here is my similar code of getting data from database via Entity Framework, wish it is useful to you.

```
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        Product GetProduct(int ID);
```

---

```
public Product GetProduct(int ID)
        {
            TestStoreEntities entities = new TestStoreEntities();
            return entities.Products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == ID);
        }
```

**web.config**

```
<connectionStrings><add name="TestStoreEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=10.157.18.36;initial catalog=TestStore;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=123456;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings></configuration>
```

**Result.**
[image]

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.